Xamarin App getting empty response from an API after a year of no issues
since of this morning all my older versions of Xamarin Form application are receiving empty string when trying  to communicate with my web API.
Ex using the .NET Https Client :
   var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(POSTValues);
   var response2 = await HTTPClient.PostAsync(APIURL, encodedContent);
   string responseString = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Status code would be 200 here but response would be : "".
It's empty for every request.
No changes were made to the app, no changes were made to the API. It's the same code that worked flawlessly for the past year.
This is in Xamarin 5.0.0.2612
However,  to make this more interesting, an unreleased update for the app running on latest available Xamarin version.... works with the same code and same unmodified API ?
Any idea what has changed that could cause the older released versions to simply stop working as of today? Honestly I'm a little shook.
I'm checking with my host to see if there were any changes to the server that would cause API to stop responding to some requests but I highly doubt so as they would notify me first.
This is Xamarin Forms application, tested on multiple brands of Android phones.
It fails on every device as of today around noon.

What do the server logs show?
